How can I simplify this combinatorics expression?
I got a expression that is related to the combinatorics, and it looks like this:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{2^{2k-1}}{k}\binom{2n-2k}{n-k}\cdot \frac{1}{\binom{2n}{n}}$$
it is from a question I've been studying, and with another approach, I got the answer:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2k-1}$$
so I think the two should be the same, which means that
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{2^{2k-1}}{k}\binom{2n-2k}{n-k}\cdot \frac{1}{\binom{2n}{n}}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2k-1}$$
and to verify this, I wrote a python program to justify. And the outcome is that the two are very likely to be the same. (I tried when $n=1$ to $n=50$, and the difference is tiny) So can anyone help me to prove it? I've tried many ways but all failed, I even asked chat-gpt but it didn't help. Thanks a lot if you can think of a way to prove it

If you got the two expressions from the same conbinatorics problem, then you have proved they are equal. Are you looking for an algebraic proof?

Yes, if there's an algebraic proof, it may be more fascinating because it doesn't care about the background

"I even asked chat-gpt" , do not do this in the future.

(I found the proof, it's shown below, after the Update)
(previous:)
I simplified your expression
$$\begin{equation}
\frac{\binom{2n-2k}{n-k}}{\binom{2n}{n}}=\frac{(2n-2k)!(n!)^2}{(2n)!((n-k)!)^2}=\frac{(n\cdot(n-1)\dots(n-k+1))^2}{2n\cdot(2n-1)\dots(2n-2k+2)}\\
=\frac{1}{2^{2k}}\frac{2n}{2n-1}\frac{2n-2}{2n-3}\dots\frac{2n-2k+2}{2n-2k+1}
\end{equation}
$$
So the equation in question becomes
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2k}\frac{2n}{2n-1}\frac{2n-2}{2n-3}\dots\frac{2n-2k+2}{2n-2k+1}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2k-1}$$
The first few $n$ gives:
$$\frac{1}{2}\frac{2}{1}=1$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\frac{4}{3}+\frac{1}{4}\frac{4}{3}\frac{2}{1}=1+\frac{1}{3}$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\frac{6}{5}+\frac{1}{4}\frac{6}{5}\frac{4}{3}+\frac{1}{6}\frac{6}{5}\frac{4}{3}\frac{2}{1}=1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\frac{8}{7}+\frac{1}{4}\frac{8}{7}\frac{6}{5}+\frac{1}{6}\frac{8}{7}\frac{6}{5}\frac{4}{3}+\frac{1}{8}\frac{8}{7}\frac{6}{5}\frac{4}{3}\frac{2}{1}=1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7}$$
I tried to use induction on it, but didn't get anywhere.
On the other hand, I tried to group the terms on the l.h.s, and I got
$$\frac{8}{7}\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{6}{5}\left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{4}{3}\left(\frac{1}{6}+\frac{2}{1}\left(\frac{1}{8}\right)\right)\right)\right)=1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7}$$
An interesting thing that I noticed is, if I replace the numbers $\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{6},\frac{1}{8}$ with ones, it suddenly becomes obvious. We get this identity:
$$\frac{8}{7}\left(1+\frac{6}{5}\left(1+\frac{4}{3}\left(1+\frac{2}{1}1\right)\right)\right)=8=2+2+2+2$$
Then I wondered, what if I inverse the order of them? And I found that
$$\frac{8}{7}\left(\frac{1}{8}+\frac{6}{5}\left(\frac{1}{6}+\frac{4}{3}\left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{2}{1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)\right)\right)=\left(1+\frac{1}{1}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{3}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{5}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{7}\right)-1$$
Because we start with $a_1=1$, then we have $a_2=\frac{4}{3}(\frac{1}{4}+1)=1+\frac{2}{3}$, next we have $\frac{6}{5}(\frac{1}{6}+a_2)=\frac{1}{5}+a_2+\frac{1}{5}a_2=a_2+\frac{1}{5}(1+a_2)=1+\frac{2}{3}+\frac{1}{5}(2+\frac{2}{3})=1+\frac{2}{3}+\frac{2}{5}+\frac{2}{3\cdot 5}$. It's not as obvious as the previous equation, but still pretty easy to prove.
I don't know if this is in the right direction of proving the equation in question, but it seems that this construction gives some interesting sequences, and I wonder what other sequences can be constructed by different sequences of coefficients.

Update 
I found a proof by induction:
Suppose we already have
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2k}\frac{2n}{2n-1}\frac{2n-2}{2n-3}\dots\frac{2n-2k+2}{2n-2k+1}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2k-1}\label{eq1}\tag{1}$$
We want to prove that
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{2k}\frac{2n+2}{2n+1}\frac{2n}{2n-1}\frac{2n-2}{2n-3}\dots\frac{2n+2-2k+2}{2n+2-2k+1}=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{2k-1}\label{eq2}\tag{2}$$
Multiply $Eq.\eqref{eq2}$ by $2n+1$, it becomes
$$\frac{2n+2}{2}+\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}\frac{2n+2}{2k}\frac{2n}{2n-1}\frac{2n-2}{2n-3}\dots\frac{2n+2-2k+2}{2n+2-2k+1}=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{2n+1}{2k-1}$$
We can re-number $k$ on the l.h.s,
$$\frac{2n+2}{2}+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2n+2}{2k+2}\frac{2n}{2n-1}\frac{2n-2}{2n-3}\dots\frac{2n+2-2k}{2n+2-2k-1}=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{2n+1}{2k-1}\label{eq3}\tag{3}$$
Multiply $Eq.\eqref{eq1}$ by $2n+1$, then subtract that from $Eq.\eqref{eq3}$. On the l.h.s, the terms in the summation match up. On the r.h.s, the first $n$ terms are cancelled, only the last term $\frac{2n+1}{2n+1}$ remains, which is one. So we want to prove that,
$$n+1+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{2n+2}{2k+2}-\frac{2n+1}{2k}\right)\frac{2n}{2n-1}\frac{2n-2}{2n-3}\dots\frac{2n-2k+2}{2n-2k+1}=1$$
Or, re-arrange it,
$$n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{2n+1}{2k}-\frac{2n+2}{2k+2}\right)\frac{2n}{2n-1}\frac{2n-2}{2n-3}\dots\frac{2n-2k+2}{2n-2k+1}$$
$$2n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{2n+1}{k}-\frac{2n+2}{k+1}\right)\frac{2n}{2n-1}\frac{2n-2}{2n-3}\dots\frac{2n-2k+2}{2n-2k+1}$$
$$2n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{2n-k+1}{k(k+1)}\right)\frac{2n}{2n-1}\frac{2n-2}{2n-3}\dots\frac{2n-2k+2}{2n-2k+1}\label{eq4}\tag{4}$$
Now, let's work backwards. Starting from the last term on the r.h.s, where $k=n$, which is
$$\left(\frac{n+1}{n(n+1)}\right)\frac{2n}{2n-1}\frac{2n-2}{2n-3}\dots\frac{4}{3}\frac{2}{1}=\frac{1}{n}\frac{2n}{2n-1}\frac{2n-2}{2n-3}\dots\frac{4}{3}\frac{2}{1}$$
To combine this with the previous term, we take $\frac{2}{1}$ to the front, and multiply to $\frac{1}{n}$. Adding this to the previous term, we get
$$\left(\frac{2}{n}+\frac{n+2}{(n-1)n}\right)\frac{2n}{2n-1}\frac{2n-2}{2n-3}\dots\frac{4}{3}=\frac{3}{n-1}\frac{2n}{2n-1}\frac{2n-2}{2n-3}\dots\frac{4}{3}=\frac{4}{n-1}\frac{2n}{2n-1}\frac{2n-2}{2n-3}\dots\frac{6}{5}$$
Next, combine with the previous term, we get
$$\left(\frac{4}{n-1}+\frac{n+3}{(n-2)(n-1)}\right)\frac{2n}{2n-1}\frac{2n-2}{2n-3}\dots\frac{6}{5}=\frac{5}{n-2}\frac{2n}{2n-1}\frac{2n-2}{2n-3}\dots\frac{6}{5}=\frac{6}{n-2}\frac{2n}{2n-1}\frac{2n-2}{2n-3}\dots\frac{8}{7}$$
I think, at this point, the pattern is pretty obvious.
Formally, let's set $t=n-k+1$ which is just $k$ in reverse order, if the previous term gives a $\frac{2t+1}{n-t}$, then we can combine it with the previous term, and the coefficient becomes
$$\frac{2t+1}{n-t}\frac{2t+2}{2t+1}+\frac{n+t+2}{(n-t-1)(n-t)}=\frac{2t+3}{n-t-1}$$
Eventually we arrive at the first term:
$$\frac{2n-1}{1}\frac{2n}{2n-1}=2n$$
which is the same as the l.h.s of $Eq.\eqref{eq4}$. The proof is complete.
It took me the entire night, manipulating the equations of $n=4$ and $n=3$, trying to see a pattern. Finally, I noticed that after some manipulation similar to the one above, the numbers magically cancelled out! I thought, hey, maybe I'm on the right track! And I tested with arbitrary $n$ and it worked! It took some effort but it's totally worth it!
I think this is a really neat result. I wonder if there is a simpler proof.

The proof is so brilliant and wonderful ! Thanks. Wish you good luck.

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{{\displaystyle #1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sr}[2]{\,\,\,\stackrel{{#1}}{{#2}}\,\,\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
& \color{#44f}{\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{2^{2k - 1} \over k}{2n - 2k \choose n - k}{1 \over
{2n \choose n}}}
\\[5mm] = & \
{1 \over {\, -1/2\,\, \choose n}\pars{-4}^{n}}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}
{2^{2k - 1} \over k}{-1/2 \choose n - k}\pars{-4}^{n - k}
\\[5mm] = & \
{1\over 2{\, -1/2\,\, \choose n}}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}
{\pars{-1}^{k} \over k}{-1/2 \choose n - k}
\\[5mm] = & \
{1\over 2{\, -1/2\,\, \choose n}}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}
{\pars{-1}^{k} \over k}\bracks{z^{n - k}}
\pars{1 + z}^{-1/2}
\\[5mm] = & \
{1\over 2{\, -1/2\,\, \choose n}}
\bracks{z^{n}}\pars{1 + z}^{-1/2}
\sum_{k = 1}^{\color{red}{\infty}}{\pars{-z}^{k} \over k}\label{1}\tag{1}
\\[5mm] = & \
{1\over 2{\, -1/2\,\, \choose n}}\bracks{z^{n}}
\pars{1 + z}^{-1/2}\,
\braces{-\ln\pars{1 - \bracks{-z}}}
\\[5mm] = & \
-\,{1\over 2{\, -1/2\,\, \choose n}}
\bracks{z^{n}}
\left.\partiald{\pars{1 + z}^{\nu}}{\nu}\right\vert_{\nu\ =\ -1/2}
\\[5mm] = & \
-\,{1\over 2{\, -1/2\,\, \choose n}}
\left.\partiald{}{\nu}{\nu \choose n}
\right\vert_{\nu\ =\ -1/2}
\\[5mm] = & \
-\,{1\over 2{\, -1/2\,\, \choose n}}
{-1/2 \choose n}
\left.\partiald{}{\nu}
\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{\nu + 1} \over \Gamma\pars{\nu - n + 1}}
\right\vert_{\nu\ =\ -1/2}
\\[5mm] = & \
{1\over 2}\bracks{\Psi\pars{{1 \over 2} - n} -
\Psi\pars{1 \over 2}}
\\[5mm] \sr{n\ \in\ \mathbb{N}}{=} & \
{1\over 2}\bracks{\Psi\pars{{1 \over 2} + n} -
\Psi\pars{1 \over 2}}
\\[5mm] = & \
{1\over 2}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\pars{%
{1 \over k + 1/2} - {1 \over k + 1/2 + n}}
\\[5mm] = & \
{1\over 2}\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}{1 \over k + 1/2} =
\bbx{\color{#44f}{%
\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over 2k - 1}}} \\ &
\end{align}
In (\ref{1}), the sum is extended to $\ds{\color{red}{\infty}}$ because $\ds{z^{k}\mbox{-power}}$ with $\ds{k > n}$ does not give any contribution to the sum. That fact occurs due to the presence $\ds{\mbox{of}~\bracks{z^{n}}}$.

Nice answer. (+1). You can differentiate ${\nu\choose n}$ using algebra by writing $$\left(\frac{1}{n!} \prod_{r=0}^{n-1} (\nu-r)\right)' = \frac{1}{n!} \prod_{r=0}^{n-1} (\nu-r) \sum_{r=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{\nu-r}.$$  Then put $\nu=-1/2$ to get $-{-1/2\choose n} \times 2 \times \sum_{r=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{2r+1}.$

@MarkoRiedel Thanks. That happens because I'm a $\Gamma$-fan. I like your approach. I'll keep it for the future. Nice to see you again.

Thanks. And thanks for presenting Egorychev method on MSE, that was where I first learned it (posts by you and Markus Scheuer).

We need to show that
$$
\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{2^{2k-1}}{k} \binom{2(n-k)}{n-k} = \binom{2n}{n} \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2k-1}
$$
The generating function for the left hand side can be represented as a product:
$$
\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \left[\frac{2^{2k} x^k}{k} \right]\left[\binom{2(n-k)}{n-k}x^{n-k}\right] =\frac{1}{2}\left[\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2^{2k} x^k}{k}\right] \left[\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \binom{2k}{k} x^k\right]
$$
The first factor evaluates to $\log\frac{1}{1-4x}$, and the second to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}}$, thus
$$
\boxed{G(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}} \log \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}}}
$$
is the closed form expression for the generating function of the LHS.

Now, let's find the generating function for the right-hand side. Let
$$
f_n = \binom{2n}{n} \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2k-1},
$$
then, taking into consideration $\binom{2n}{n} = \frac{2(2n-1)}{n}\binom{2(n-1)}{n-1}$, we can say that
$$
f_n = \frac{2(2n-1)}{n}f_{n-1} + \frac{1}{2n-1}\binom{2n}{n}
$$
with the base case $f_0 = 0$. Getting rid of denominators, that turns into
$$
n(2n-1) f_n = 2(2n-1)^2 f_{n-1} + n \binom{2n}{n},
$$
Let $\Delta = x \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$, then in terms of generating functions this rewrites as a diffeq:
$$
\boxed{\Delta(2\Delta-1) F(x) = 2(2\Delta-1)^2 xF(x) + \Delta \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}}}
$$
In terms of just derivatives, it translates into
$$
\boxed{2x(1 - 4x) F''(x) + (1-16x) F'(x)  - 2F(x) = \frac{2}{(1-4x)^{3/2}}}
$$
It admits a unique analytic solution subject to $F(0)=f_0 = 0$, and one can formally verify that $G(x)$ satisfies the differential equation.

Bonus: if you only know the equation, and you don't know the solution in advance, you can plug it into Wolfram and see that the general form of the solution here is
$$
F(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}}\left[c_1 + c_2 \arcsin(2\sqrt x) + \log\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}}\right]
$$
